# Kendo date picker angular js

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, model

I'm having an issue when formatting a date in my locale and my date picker looks like this:

```
input id="logdate" kendo-date-picker="logdate" k-options="logdateOptions" data-ng-model="logFilter.date" k-ng-model="logFilter.date" style="width: 100%;"
```

where logFilter.Date is coming from the server in this format: `2020-01-06T00:00:00+05:30` and is displayed as it is. I'm expecting it to be: `2020-01-06T10:56:00+05:30` instead. i.e correct time with date.

Answer (score 0):

We can edit it by using moment.js

moment(object_name).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

and for concatenating time

var currentHours = ("0" + $scope.CurrentDate.getUTCHours()).slice(-2);

var currentMinutes = ("0" + $scope.CurrentDate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);

var currentSeconds = ("0" + $scope.CurrentDate.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

object_name = moment(object_name).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T" + currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + "Z";